# Как установить PowerShell или убрать это сообщение в vs code

Tags: visual-studio-code

[image]

```
PowerShell 7.2.5
Copyright (c) Microsoft Corporation.

https://aka.ms/powershell
Type 'help' to get help.

PS C:\Users\mklim\OneDrive\Рабочий стол\Java Project>
```

Я пробовал переходит по этой ссылке и скачивал Powershell, но при установке пишет, что новая версия уже установлена. Как можно скрыть это сообщение? мешает очень

Comment: С флажком `-NoLogo` попробуйте.

Answer (score 0):

Возможно поможет команда `clear`/`cls`/`ctrl`+`k` в терминале.
Терминал не очистится, все сообщения ДО будут видны, НО они поднимутся вверх, и только при скроле вверх(по вашему желаю), вы сможете их увидеть.